# How do i Show UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurl (MapCurl)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

How do i Show ModalTransitionStyle Like this?

[image]

I would like to show Corner itself as i mentioned picture.

If i touch Corner, want to open next View....

Answer (score 2):

```
-(void)goToPage{

 //do stuff...

 // start the animated transition
 [UIView beginAnimations:@"page transition" context:nil];
 [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
 [UIView setAnimationTransition:flipUp ? UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp : UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown forView:self.view cache:YES];

 //insert your new subview
 //[self.view insertSubview:currentPage.view atIndex:self.view.subviews.count];

  // commit the transition animation
  [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
 return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UIView* view = viewController.view;
view.frame = self.view.window.bounds;
[UIView transitionWithView:self.view.window
                  duration:0.2 
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp 
                animations:^(void) {
                    [self.view.window addSubview:view];
                } 
                completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                    [viewController.view removeFromSuperview];
                    [viewController presentModalViewController:viewController
                                                      animated:NO];
                }];
    enter code here
```

Answer (score 1):

It uses UIPageViewController. See here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html
I used it in one of our apps and it is working.